# distributing config over a windows domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration-management

I have a Windows C++ application, that's run on lots of machines within the same Windows 2008 domain. I'm also the (not very good) domain administrator.

What I'd like to do, is somehow distribute global config for the application, across the domain. Something like group policy, where a policy is applied to lots of machines.

The only config I need is a single key and value. My app will check the config once when it's clicked on.

Does anyone know any mechanisms for distributing config over a domain like this? Ideally point and click, no software to install on the domain servers and so on.

I'm posting this on serverfault, not stackoverflow as it's more of a config question, rather than a programming question.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try exporting the key from the registry then distributing it as a script to run and insert into the registry at login.

Better solution is, if you are a programmer, to have a small config server running centrally that your application "checks in" with at startup and configure things that way (falling back to a local config if the master config isn't found).

It shouldn't be too hard, though, to have a .reg file imported from a batch file at user login as long as the user has permissions to write to that section of the registry.